# modify/override filter provided by Grails plugin

Tags: grails, filter

In my Grails project, I would like to override a filter provided by a plugin so it better fits my needs.

More specifically, the filter is defined so it is applied to all actions on all controllers: `filterName(controller:"*", action:"*") { ... }`, and I want to restrict it to only certain controllers.

I tried to create a filter class in my project with the same name as the filter I want to override, but the result is both filters are being executed on every request.

So does anyone know how to change/override/(or even deactivate) a filter provided by a plugin? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dmahapatro's answer put me in the way to finding a solution: the key concept is getting access to the `filterInterceptor` bean, which contains the definitions of all filters in the Grails application. It can be accessed e.g. in the `BootStrap.groovy` file in order to modify available filters at application startup:

```
class BootStrap {
    def filterInterceptor

    def init = { servletContext ->
        // modify myPluginFilter provided by plugin so it 
        // is only applied to certain requests
        def myPluginFilterHandler = filterInterceptor.handlers.find{ it.filterConfig.name == 'myPluginFilter' }
        myPluginFilterHandler.filterConfig.scope.controller = 'myController'
        myPluginFilterHandler.filterConfig.scope.action = 'myAction'
        myPluginFilterHandler.afterPropertiesSet()

        log.info "myPluginFilter scope modified"
    }

    ...
}
```

This code is executed once at application startup and it finds the filter `myPluginFilter` (e.g., defined in a plugin) and changes its scope (the controller and action to which it is applied).

The filter could be destroyed instead of redefined by removing `myPluginFilterHandler` from the `filterInterceptor.handlers` collection.

Comment: The downside of this solution is that if filter definitions are reloaded (e.g. when a filter is modified or added in development mode), the modified filter will keep its original definition, because the code in `BootStrap.groovy` is executed only once when the application starts. However, this should not be a problem in production mode.

Comment: I went for a solution where I have a plugin that specifies `def loadAfter = ['filters']` and then in `doWithApplicationContext` modifies `handlers` collection on `filterInterceptor` bean

Answer (score 0):

You can try `clearing` the `handlers` from the new filter class in your project something like:

```
blockPluginFilter(controller:"*", action:"*"){
    before = {
        def compInterceptor = applicationContext.getBean("filterInterceptor", CompositeInterceptor)
        compInterceptor.handlers?.clear()
    }
}
```

Each `filter` has a configured spring bean `filterInterceptor` registered as a `CompositeInterceptor` which has an handle to all the `filters` represented as `handlers`. If you clear the `handlers` in the new filter (if it was not late) then you can avoid executing the `filter` from the `plugin`. You can create another filter in your project filter class to handle your customized logic. This would work only if the plugin's filter executes after this filter. You can clear the `handlers` in any other place but before the plugin's filter is hit.

Comment: thanks for your answer; it gave me insight on how to modify filter definitions programatically at runtime. I modified your solution by accessing the `filterInterceptor` only once in `BootStrap.groovy` and then changing the definition of the filter. I posted it as a separate anwer and accepted it.